# In Byobu select with the mouse within the same split screen only

Tags: linux, tmux, byobu

In Byobu, with split screen, how is it possible to click with my mouse and select multiple lines within the same split screen only and not the whole terminal line?
If I try to select text with my mouse, it is selecting the whole terminal line that includes more than one split screens.

Comment: I don't think it is, unless your terminal emulator (hypothetically) works with Byobu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write here the way I decided to do this.

In order o be able to copy multiple lines with the mouse from a spited window in byobu and not select characters from the borders and other spited windows, I first maximize (zoom) the current window by pressing **"Ctr + a z"** , and select the multiple lines with the mouse. If i press again the same key sequence the zooming will stop and will have again the window arrangement as before.

(The Alt-F11 proposed by Moning2 will also do the job but you would have changed your windows arrangement because you will have moved the split to a new window.)

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Comment: fwiw "Shift+F11" should do the same as "Ctrl+a z"

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Will give the pane its own window
- Highlight and copy the text you want
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Will move the pane back to its original place in the split

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable `mode-mouse` using `Alt-F12`.
   You'll see the status in the bottom left corner. You may need to press it multiple times.
2. Select the text you'd like to copy.
   It will automatically be copied.
3. Use `Alt-Insert` to paste in any split or window.

Do note that this only works within the same byobu instance. If you'd like to paste outside the byobu instance:

1. Press `Alt-F11` inside the split you'd like to copy from, to move it
   into its own window.
2. Make sure `mode-mouse` is OFF.
3. Use your regular method of copying and pasting from a terminal window.

Comment: But this doesn't work with `set mouse=a` on `~/.vimrc`. Any other suggestions ?